# Getting String List after join of two tables

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

I have two tables Card(cardID, cardName, setName) and Set(setID, setName, setMark). I want add card names from a specific set to `ComboBox` items.

```
String setMark = comboBoxSetMark.SelectedItem.ToString();
comboBoxCardName.ItemsSource = (from cards in dataContext.Cards
                                            join sets in dataContext.Sets
                                            on cards.setID equals sets.setID
                                            where sets.setMark == setMark
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                cards.cardName
                                            }).ToList();
```

I get something like that in `comboBox` items selection:

```
{card name = Sylvan Caryatid}
```

How to get just cardName value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting new anonymous objects in your `Select`. And WPF automatically calls `ToString()` method of this object for rendering items in the view. The compiler ***generates an override*** of `ToString()` that displays the value of ***each of the public properties in your anonymous object***. 
The result of `ToString()` for anonymous objects would be:

> { Name1 = Value1, Name2 = Value2 }

The reason of this "unexpected" result is that. You can solve this problem by selecting `string` from your query.

So, instead of that, select `string` objects:

```
comboBoxCardName.ItemsSource = (from cards in dataContext.Cards
                                join sets in dataContext.Sets
                                    on cards.setID equals sets.setID
                                where sets.setMark == setMark
                                select cards.cardName
                                ).ToList();
```

***Additional:***

The better solution will be to create a new model for your controls which have to display name, but select id of the selected item.

For this purpose you can create a new class:

```
public class MyItem
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
}
```

And then get List from your query:

```
comboBoxCardName.ItemsSource = (from cards in dataContext.Cards
                                join sets in dataContext.Sets
                                    on cards.setID equals sets.setID
                                where sets.setMark == setMark
                                select new { cardName = cards.cardName, cardId = cards.cardID }
                                ).AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(x => new MyItem { Id = x.cardName, Name= x.cardId })
                               .ToList();
```

And then set `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` for your control in `.xaml`:

```
<ComboBox ...
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

Comment: For `select cards.cardID` it will generate List<int>, right?

Comment: @pochmurnik Yes, exactly.

Comment: @pochmurnik I have updated my answer also, if you want to display name and get selected item's id.

Comment: This also can be useful, first I need figure out couple things here. Thank you.

Comment: i have a problem with this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926473/displaymemberpath-and-selectedvaluepath-issue-while-using-linq-to-generate-combo