# DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath issue while using LINQ to generate ComboBox.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxAccountName" DisplayMemberPath="AccountName" SelectedValuePath="AccountID" />
```

ItemComboBoxAccount class:

```
public class ItemComboBoxAccount
{
    private int accountID;
    private String accountName;

    public int AccountID
    {
        get { return accountID; }
        set { accountID = value; }
    }

    public String AccountName
    {
        get { return accountName; }
        set { accountName = value; }
    }
}
```

LINQ query:

```
comboBoxAccountName.ItemsSource = (from accounts in dataContext.Accounts
                                  select new { accountName = accounts.accountName, accountID = accounts.accountID }
                                  ).AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select(x => new ItemComboBoxAccount { AccountID = x.accountID, AccountName = x.accountName })
                                  .ToList();
```

ComboBox shows no items, there are as many rows as accounts in Accounts, but rows remain blank. I want display AccountName.

Comment: try making the fields properties instead

Comment: Ok, I changed this class. Now I can see items in ComboBox, but when I select any, ComboBox remains blank (without any item selected).

But what is the difference between properties and public attributes in that case?

Comment: I don't bother myself with the technical differences, I know a lot of stuff in WPF only works on properties though.

Comment: But still, I can't display Selected Item.

Comment: just googling that, not sure why i'm afraid.

Comment: Without that, I need back to getting ID by querying it.

Comment: @pochmurnik Have you tried to set `ItemsSource` to some `List<ItemComboBoxAccount >`? Because, I  have just tested it and it must work. `List<ItemComboBoxAccount> myList = new List<ItemComboBoxAccount>();
            myList.Add(new ItemComboBoxAccount() { AccountID = 15, AccountName = "Name1" });
            comboBoxAccountName.ItemsSource = myList;`

Comment: I generate ItemsSource in two places. First under InitializeComponent() and then everytime when TabControl item is changed. Now I commented the 2nd one and it is working. Why? How can I reload comboBox items everytime when tabControl item is changing?

Comment: @pochmurnik May be you are changing `DataContext`? Put `this.DataContext=this;` before setting the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Still, when I choose item from comboBox it remains blank.

Comment: You could try binding the SelectedItem to a new property in your ViewModel.

Comment: Why the double select in your LINQ expression? Seems to be redundant.

Comment: The solution is very embarrassing... I forgot that I left this line in `tabControl_SelectionChanged`:
    `comboBoxAccountName.ItemsSource = dataContext.Accounts.Select(i => i.accountName);` and it was always changing `comboBox` items. Should I delete this topic? It is useless i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,for entities I would use lambda expression to set the item source. That way I can dynamically populate the combo box from one method without having to use data binding.

I use sql and then create a instance of the db in the context.tt file.

Manipulate the following for your own use:

Going to use "BankEntities" to represent the db entity.

Try:

```
combobox.itemsource = BankEntities.instance.BankAccounts.where(x => x.AccountName == x.AccountName).ToList();
```

or

```
combobox.itemsource = BankEntities.instance.BankAccounts.where(x => x.AccountId == x.AccountId).ToList();
```